# How can I play a SWF file placed into Resources folder

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, flash, webbrowser-control

I need to make a Windows application in which, at loading time, I need to play a Flash (.swf) file in WebBrowser. But I can play the Flash file directly from hard disk to WebBrowser control. Here I need to play the .swf file in the Resources folder and load it in WebBrowser control. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you play flash from hard disk?

Comment: just given the path in navigating method of webbrowser control.

Comment: Not sure if it will work but have you tested getting a stream to the resource? Try this. If not, what about writing the stream into a temporary file?

Comment: You can write the swf to the temp directory at runtime, and use the temp path for the embed. You can't stream directly from resources.

Answer (score 0):

```
    System.Reflection.Assembly thisExe;
    thisExe = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    System.IO.Stream file = thisExe.GetManifestResourceStream("Namespace.Filename");
    byte[] data = Properties.Resources.Filename;
    file.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the flash(.swf ) file as embedded resource.

use this method it works as u expect.

```
   private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream sr = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("namespace.file.swf");
        if (sr == null) return;
        var reader = new BufferedStream(sr);
        string tempfile = Path.GetTempFileName() + ".swf";
        var data = new byte[reader.Length];
        reader.Read(data, 0, (int)reader.Length);
        File.WriteAllBytes(tempfile, data);
        webBrowser1.Url = new Uri(tempfile);
    }
```

Hope it helps.